# Get last element of array with for var of

Tags: javascript, arrays

i switch to using :

```
for (var element of elements)
```

instead of :

```
for (var i in elements)
```

Why? Because i was creating array prototypes and when i use `var i in`, the prototypes are considered as an element of that array.

My question is can i know if my element is the last element of that array, do i need to create another variable and do increment everytime till that variable is equal to elements.lentgh - 1 ?

Comment: `if( element === elements[elements.length-1] )`?

Comment: Can't help wondering why can't you use array comprehension functions (forEach, map, filter, reduce etc.); they get index as a second param.

Comment: That's why `for...in...` is not meant for arrays but objects...

Comment: @Martijn the element must be unique ? ( if the second element is equal to the last element for instance )

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing something like:

```
for (var element of elements){
    if(element === elements[elements.length-1]){
         // Last element being processed here
    }
}
```

It may be better to use `Array.prototype.forEach` based on your usecase

```
elements.forEach(function(element, index, array){
     if(index === elements.length-1){
         // Last element
     }
})
```

Comment: Yes, the element must be unique for the first method to work (unless your array elements are reference types like Objects or Arrays - in which case, it will still work because the references are being compared)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
        var i, len, text;
        for ( i = 0,   len = elements.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) {
                   text = elements[i] + "";
                   if(text === elements[elements.length-1]){
                      console.log('last', text);
    }        
}


var elements = [5, 15, 78, 20,43,77];
        var i, len, text;
        for ( i = 0,   len = elements.length, text = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   text = elements[i] ;
                   if(text === elements[elements.length-1]){
                      console.log('last', text);
    }        
}
```